# How to remove a broken installation of glibc

Tags: software-installation, glibc

I just attempted to install `glibc` version `2.19` to my computer as follows:

1) I cloned the `glibc` git repo with

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
```

2) I checked out version `2.19` with

```
$ git co tags/glibc-2.19
```

3) I made a directory `objdir` in my home directory, and built the installation there with

```
$ cd ~/objdir
$ ~/glibc/configure --prefix=$HOME
$ make
```

4) I tested the make with

```
$ make check
```

This gave me an error, but some webpage I found with a Google search told me this particular error wasn't a big deal.  (I wish I could remember what the error and webpage were, but I can't, and I found the webpage using a computer I don't have access to right now, so it's not on my web history where I'm typing now.)

5) I attempted to install `glibc` with

```
$ make install
```

This is where things went crazy for me.  The installation failed midway, and, now using a broken `glibc`, my user account completely stopped working.

Luckily, my system administrator was able to move my `.bashrc` -- which was pointing to the broken `glibc` under my home directory -- and revert me to a default `.bashrc`.  So I can log into my account again and do stuff.

**My question is, what should I do to completely remove the broken installation of `glibc` that resides under my home directory?**

## EDIT

When I run `make uninstall` in `~/objdir`, I get this error:

```
[dbliss@nx1 objdir]$ make uninstall
make -r PARALLELMFLAGS="" -C /home/despo/dbliss/glibc objdir=`pwd` uninstall
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/despo/dbliss/glibc'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/despo/dbliss/glibc'
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

Comment: Why can't you remove it? What's wrong with "rm -rf ./glibc"?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin so there is no glibc file in my home directory.  there are `etc`, `bin`, `lib`, and `include` directories, and some of the files in these directories are part of `glibc`.  my question really is, which files are part of `glibc`?  because i've installed other stuff to these directories that isn't part of `glibc`, and i don't want to delete that stuff.

Comment: Looks like that says "make uninstall" is unsupported

Comment: @RyanBabchishin right.  i shared it only in case there might be some option i could use with `make uninstall` that would make it work.  but i think there just isn't an `uninstall` that was included in `glibc`.